# When can/can't one switch limits?

Tags: analysis, reference-request

Is there some nice article where I can find isolated some concrete theorems and counterexamples on when can one switch the order of two integrals, differentiate under the integral sign, differentiate a series term by term, pass a limit into an integral, etc.? (Or what is your technique to remember when one can/can't switch the order of the limits?)

Comment: If it's ugly, look it up. If it's nice, swap it ^^ I guess you'll have to remember your standard Calculus theorems by heart - some are very important so they are worth keeping in mind. A general reference would be any book on Calculus.

Comment: You should in particular be aware of [Fubini-Tonelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) for switching order of integration, and [Monotone-Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) and [Dominated-Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) for pushing limits into/outof summations or integrals.

Comment: The idea of collecting some counterexamples around this topic has merit, but you would help your Reader by focusing on a specific set, such such as interchanging order of integration and a sequential limit of integrands.  As stated the theme of switching limits is broad, in some ways the outlines of a classical theory of analysis.